# Okhttp3 block program

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, okhttp

I'm working on a library that is a file which get some high order functions

My file is like:

```kotlin
import okhttp3.*

private val client by lazy { OkHttpClient() }


fun fn() {
    client.newCall(request(url)).enqueue(callback)
    do stuff ...
}
...
```

When I call some `fn()`, it continues running on background blocking the program to exit, even there is no more instructions to execute. I suspect it happens because of `.enqueue(callback)` which is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade to the latest OkHttp 4.7.2, then it won't block your program as the threads are now daemon threads.

Clean shutdown is documented in the API docs for OkHttpClient.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/

```
client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
client.connectionPool().evictAll();
```